# display particular product name and image in custom admin grid page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

[image: this is my admin grid here in view that opens the page in that page]
[image: in this page I want to display that particular product name and image in it]

I want to display product name and product image in a custom page in admin grid that page opens on view click in action